# Magento 1.9 - get signed in user detail with token and custom API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, user

I want to access Logged In user detail with Oauth 1 Token and Custom API.

I have an Angular app that I can log in with OAuth 1 but I need to show Firstname and Lastname and profile picture in my App.

I use Magento Version 1.9